# Unable to launch activity when taking bitmap from gallery. Can any one suggest a solution?

Tags: android

I have an activity lets say Activity1 and I take images from camera or library by launching those default activities from this activity.

I take get the image perfectly via the `onActivityResult` method. This method is implemented in `Activity1`.

Now, I put the retrieved image in `Activity1` in the `Intent.putExtra(...)` when launching `Activity2`. I launch the activity via the following code..

```
//Bitmap handle in Activity1. This holds the bitmap retrieved from camera or gallery.
Bitmap my_bitmap_image;

//Now, on click of a button in Activity1
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("MyBitmapImage",this.my_bitmap_image);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Now, an odd stuff occurs. When I take get the bitmap by camera anytime, the Activity2 gets launched properly from the above code. But if I get the bitmap by gallery anytime, then Activity2 never launches from the above code. No errors, nothing. Seems like the code just does nothing. What could be this ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that this would silently fail, with absolutely no error message. Please check logcat again. You might also try putting your code that starts Activity2 in a try/catch block, and then run it in the debugger, with a breakpoint in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing

```
intent.putExtra("MyBitmapImage",this.my_bitmap_image);
```

you are taking advantage of the fact that a `Bitmap` implements `Parcelable` via which it can be put in an `Intent`. According to the [the source code for bitmap](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/2.2.3/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java) (search for `writeToParcel`), a `Bitmap` cannot be parcelled if it is `recycled`. It would seem highly likely to me that an image from the gallery is recycled.

The solution is to make your own copy of a `Bitmap` if `bitmap.isRecycled()` returns true. It may well be there is an issue with immuatble `Bitmap`s as well, but I can't prove that.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll have to check on this.